# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'targets'

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am getting an error, when I run the below code.

```
def __init__(self, model, sess, loss_fn=None):
    """
    To generate the White-box Attack Agent.
    :param model: the target model which should have the input tensor, the target tensor and the loss tensor.
    :param sess: the tensorflow session.
    :param loss_fn: None if using original loss of the model.
          
    """
    self.model = model
    self.input_tensor = model.inputs[0]
    self.output_tensor = model.outputs[0]
    self.target_tensor = model.targets[0]
    self._sample_weights = model.sample_weights[0]
    if loss_fn is None:
        self.loss_tensor = model.total_loss
        self.gradient_tensor = K.gradients(self.loss_tensor, self.input_tensor)[0]
    else:
        self.set_loss_function(loss_fn)
    self.sess = sess
```

error:

```
self.target_tensor = model.targets[0]  ,   AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'targets'
```

I am working with Tensorflow 1.14.0 ,keras 2.2.4-tf and python 3.6.13.how can I resolve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `model` argument that your function is using is apparently talking about a unique class that isn't part of the default Keras or Tensorflow.  You need to make sure that the `model` object you're passing the function is an instance of the appropriate class.  Or, alternatively, you can jerry rig it by doing something like this:

```py
# whatever code instantiates the `model` would be here
...
...

model.targets = [ "targets of an appropriate structure and type go here" ]
```

Then when you pass that `model` object to the function, it will have a `targets` attribute to be accessed.  But it's better to just use the right object in the first place.

Or, the third option: just comment out the offending line and hope it isn't actually used anywhere (if it's being set, it's probably used somewhere or other though).

```py
def __init__(self, model, sess, loss_fn=None):
    """
    To generate the White-box Attack Agent.
    :param model: the target model which should have the input tensor, the target tensor and the loss tensor.
    :param sess: the tensorflow session.
    :param loss_fn: None if using original loss of the model.
          
    """
    self.model = model
    self.input_tensor = model.inputs[0]
    self.output_tensor = model.outputs[0]
    #self.target_tensor = model.targets[0]
    self._sample_weights = model.sample_weights[0]
    if loss_fn is None:
        self.loss_tensor = model.total_loss
        self.gradient_tensor = K.gradients(self.loss_tensor, self.input_tensor)[0]
    else:
        self.set_loss_function(loss_fn)
    self.sess = sess
```

Comment: For this problem I have installed tf-gpu 1.13.1 and now it is working.  :) thanks for your answer.